# R Model returning the error: Too many open devices

Tags: r, azure

I've been working on the creation of a training model in R for MS Azure. When I initially set up the model it all worked fine. Now it's continuously returning the below:

`{"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.","details":[{"code":"FailedToEvaluateRScript","target":"Score Model (RPackage)","message":"The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in png(file = \"3e25ea05d5bc49d683f4471ff40780bcrViz%03d.png\", bg = \"transparent\") : \n  too many open devices\n"}]}}`

I haven't changed anything, and have looked around online only to find references to other issues. My code is as follows:

**Trainer R Script**

```
        # Modify Datatype,  factor Level, Replace NA to 0 
        x <- dataset
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {
                if (class(x[[i]]) == "character") {
                        #Convert Type
                        x[[i]] <-  type.convert(x[[i]])

                        #Apply Levels 
                        # levels(x[[i]]) <-   levels(cols_modeled[, names(x)[i]]) # linked with levels in model
                }
                if (is.numeric(x[[i]]) && is.na(x[[i]]) ){
                        #print("*** Updating NA to 0")
                        x[[i]] <- 0
                }

        }
        df1 <- x 
        rm(x)

        set.seed(1234)

        model <-  svm(Paid ~ ., data= df1, type= "C")
```

**Scorer R Script**

```
library(e1071)

    scores <- data.frame( predicted_result = predict(model, dataset))
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I have got a feeling that this has less to do with your R script and more to do with azure instance that you are working on. Maybe there are too many instances open ? I am not sure though just guessing.

Comment: @RonakShah - that was my initial thought too; however I'm running another model alongside this one and it works every time.